# Advantages of SSD over a USB flash drive with similar capacity?

Tags: usb, ssd, usb-flash-drive

I'm looking for a portable storage fast solution.

If we look at some 128 GB SSD drives, you can see prices ranging (for internal drives) from 50 AUD to about 100 AUD. Couldn't find any external ones. So assuming I'll take an internal one I'll need some kind of adapter to make it work with USB.

And then, there are some 128 GB USB flash drives, that range from 40 to 60 AUD (at least in the local retailer I'm looking at).

What are the advantages of a 100$ SSD over any USB flash drives? Is it only speed? A fast USB 3 flash drive is fast enough for my requirements. Is there anything else?

Comment: the advantage is that SSD are fixed drive, so they allow several partitions, while flash drives report itself as removable drives and here only 1 partition is possible in windows.

Answer (score -1):

Get a USB 3.0 2.5" rack (under 10AUD), get an SSD and there you have your storage solution.

Note that even on USB 3 you will not get the speed or the access time the SSD would have if used internally, but it will still out-perform any memory stick.

Since there are usb flash drives that exceed 100MB/s in reads I'd say using a racked SSD may prove not that comfortable.

A truly high speed solution is Samsung's T3 which consists of an SSD working via USB 3.1.

Comment: "What are the advantages of a 100$ SSD over any USB flash drives?" - does it worth to buy an SSD if used as external, or it's advantage exists only if it's used internally? I feel your post doesn't answer the question. "SSD working via USB 3.1." - that also requires a pc with USB 3.1:(

Comment: It's a matter of comfort vs. a little more speed,  because at the specified budget range you can find 128GB SSDs.

Comment: please edit your answer instead of answering in a comment. Why would external SSD be faster then a flash drive. Isn't already for the flash drive limitating factor is USB's speed?